# Is this LCD monitor matrix damage or is something else wrong?

Tags: lcd, repair

The monitor has a vertical line and a part of its screen is not working properly.

Can this be fixed by replacing the matrix or is it something else?

[image: Photograph of LCD monitor]

Comment: seem to be a choc, so it will be difficult to repair that for cheaper than replacing the screen

Comment: Something else.

Comment: The FET column transistor is shorted & damaged beyond repair. Considering the cost has come down by a factor of 10 over the last 20 years, even good ones can be found tossed on the curb-side here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The panel is cracked in the bottom right corner (the triangular white shape with black fringing).

If you look up the product name or take apart the frame, you might find out the panel reference and see if you can buy a spare.

However, this may not make much economic sense.